# Custom post type permalink structure to include the taxonomy

Tags: custom-post-types, permalinks

I have a blog and I want to make a modification to my custom post type to include the taxonomy term in the permalink. For example I have a custom post type named "my_services" and I have a custom post type to called "my_service_cats".

```
register_post_type( 'my_services', $args);
register_taxonomy( 'my_service_cats', 'my_services', $args);
```

In the custom post type I currently have the following items:

Hotel 1 / Hotel 2 / Hotel 3

The custom taxonomy contains the following terms:

Hotels / Rooms / Houses

Currently the url is

www.domain.com/services/hotel-1

and what I want it to be is

www.domain.com/hotels/hotel-1

I have been messing with the custom post type permalinks but the only thing I have managed to do is to create more problems with the posts categories that I already have.

Can you please help on how should I go about creating this structure?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
   $args['rewrite']=array('slug'=>'/%my_service_cats%/');
    register_post_type( 'my_services', $args);
    register_taxonomy( 'my_service_cats', 'my_services', $args);
```

Comment: Hello Rajeev, thank you for your post. Can you please give some more information on how should I go about implementing this because I just added it above the registration of the post type and seems that when I have 

www.domain.com/hotels/hotel-1 it redirects to www.domain.com/services/hotel-1 

I am must be missing something there!

Comment: @nickast it should be included in registering post type not above registering post type.. this has now created duplication of rewrite rule probably in your case, so now remove extra code, and include rewrite parameter as i specified in restering post type args.